# SonarQube fails to see overridden equals when subclass declares it final

Tags: java, sonarqube

Consider the following class

```
public class A {
   public boolean equals(Object obj){
      ...
   }
}

public class C extends A {
    public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
       ...
    } 
}
```

SonarQube analysis fails to see `C` overidden `equals` method of class `A` due to `C::equals` being final.

Which causes the following violation:

> Subclasses that add fields should override "equals" (squid:S2160)

So the question is why does this rule triggers on this situation? The `C::equals` method has indeed overidden `A::equals` (the signature stays the same - making the method final does not change the signature).

Isn't this a bug?

SonarJava 5.4

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Based on what rule should SonarQube (what version and plugins do you use?) find this issue?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam updated with question

Comment: @JeroenHeier sonarqube 7.2.1, squid:S2160. Existed in 6.3 too

Comment: @Sa'ad, what's your version of SonarJava? You can find it in *Administration > Marketplace*

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam 5.4 (build 14284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a **False Positive**. SonarJava is currently not able to support such cases, relations of inheritance between class being only computed from child to parent class in the semantic engine.

The following JIRA ticket has been created to handle it: [SONARJAVA-2818](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2818?jql=text%20~%20%22equals%22%20and%20project%20%3D%20sonarjava%20and%20resolution%20%3D%20unresolved)